# $(Ax,x)>0 \forall x$ implies $A$ selfadjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I read in Reed & Simons's Functional Analysis (Vol.1, pg. 194) that a positive operator, i.e, an operator $A$ such that $(Ax,x)>0 \forall x$ on a complex Hilbert space is selfadjoint, but this doesn't hold for real Hilbert spaces. The proof uses the fact that if $(Ax,x)$ is real for all x then $(Ax,x)=(x,Ax)$ for all x and then they use the polarization identity and say that in the complex case we can recover $(Ax,y)$ by knowing $(Ax,x)$ for all $x$, but that this is not possible in the real case.

I actually don't understand how can we recover $(Ax,y)$ by knowing $(Ax,x)$ for all $x$ nor why this holds only in the complex case. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Consider the case with $x+y$ and $x+iy$ you will recover $(Ax,y)$. Without $i$ we will lose $1$ condition.

Comment: Note that in the real case the statement is wrong. See e.g. $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $x^TAx = \|x\|^2$, but $A$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the complex case:

$(A(x+y),x+y)=(Ax,x)+(Ay,y)+(Ay,x)+(Ax,y)$
$(A(x+iy),x+iy)=(Ax,x)+(Ay,y)+i(Ay,x)-i(Ax,y)$

Then you have two equations for two variables $(Ax,y)$ and $(Ay,x)$

In the real case, you will lose 1 equation because there is no $i$.

Comment: Ok yes! Now everything is clear :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is self-adjoint (to include the real case) then since you know $(Az,z)$ for all $z$ then you compute:

$$(A(x+y),x+y)=(Ax,x)+(Ay,y)+2(Ax,y),$$ from where

$$(Ax,y)=\frac{(A(x+y),x+y)-(Ax,x)-(Ay,y)}{2}.$$

Alternatively,

$$(A(x+y),x+y)=(Ax,x)+(Ay,y)+2(Ax,y),$$ and

$$(A(x-y),x-y)=(Ax,x)+(Ay,y)-2(Ax,y),$$ from where

$$(Ax,y)=\frac{(A(x+y),x+y)-(A(x-y),x-y)}{4}.$$

Comment: This means that the result is also valid in the real case, isn't it? Is Reed & Simons wrong in this case?

Comment: He just assume that $A$ is self-adjoint, which is not true in general. See my post.

Comment: Note that, as @Mr.T has said, I am assuming self-adjointness. In other case, the result doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_k\}_{k \in \alpha}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$.  Consider setting $x = e_k$, $x = e_j + e_k$, and $x = e_j + ie_k$.

This allows us to go from $(Ax,x) = (x,Ax)$ to $(A e_j,e_k) = (e_j,A e_k)$ for all $j,k \in \alpha$, so that $(A x,y) = (x,A y)$ for all $x,y \in H$.

As for the real case: consider the situation in which $A^* = -A$.